# scrolling listview causes buttons to be invisible

Tags: android, listview

I have a list view which contains a button in each row of the list.
Based upon a field, I want to make this button invisible.

My getView method inside adapter is shown below.

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Activity activity = (Activity) getContext();
                View view = convertView;

                if (convertView == null) {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
                    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow, null);
                }

                final Details details = getItem(position);
                Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn);

                if(details.check()) {
                    btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
    }
```

When I load this page the data comes correctly. But when simply scroll through this list, then this button is getting invisible. Whats the reason for this? When I remove that `if` section, then i will get buttons for all rows, even if i scrolls. Is there any problem giving `invisible` inside `getView()`. Please reply. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following:

```
if(details.check()) {
   btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
else {
   btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

and...it had better use

```
LayoutInflater.from(getContext())
```

instead of `activity.getLayoutInflater()`

Answer (score 0):

set the clickable property of listview false in xml or like:

```
getListView().setClickable(false);
```